# Read txt file within iWatch using swift

Tags: swift, file, apple-watch, watchos

I am trying to read a TXT file on my apple-watch 3 and I did the follows:

- copied the file on both Watch App and WatchKit Extension folders
- added both files Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

In my WatchKit controller I wrote the following lines of code:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "levels", ofType: "txt")
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path!){...}
```

and seems at runtime I get **nil** *path* every time

How can I read txt files within the iWatch?